# Trying to track down the textual source of a Jewish quote about a Rabbi Neskizh

Tags: pregnancy-birth, quotations, story-identification

I found the below quote in a a book called *Spiritual Midwifery.* I would love to know if the quote is real, and where it comes from. Thanks!

The Quote:

> Rabbi Mordecai of Neskizh said to his son, the rabbi of Kovel: “My son, my son! He who does not feel the pains of a woman giving birth within a circuit of 50 miles, who does not suffer with her, and pray that her suffering may be assuaged, is not worthy to be called a zaddik.”

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=gs8RAQAAIAAJ&q=%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%AA%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9A%20%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9C%20%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA&dq=%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%AA%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9A%20%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9C%20%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwja-q-y17P3AhUNyaQKHSBrDG0Q6AF6BAgGEAE).

ואמר שסיפר לו אחיו הקאוולר זצוקלה"ה איך שאביהם הנעסכיזו זצוקלה"ה אמר לו " בני הלא מי שאינו מרגיש חבלי לידה ממש כמו שיש להיולדת שהיא בתוך חמשים מייל סביבותיו כדי להתפלל עבורה לעשות לה
טובה וכי איזה שם צדיק ראוי לו

Comment: With help of your link, and some googling, I found the quote brought at the beginning of the book [זכרון טוב](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3884&pgnum=4) by יצחק בן ליב לנדא.

Comment: @TamirEvan Nice.